# Website header display differently on two different computers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I came across something that I didn't think was possible, but I have a different header display on two different machines for the same exact website, one of which displays fine, and the other one being a broken mess. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPCpQ.png) the display on PC, which is the right one, and [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6mry.png) the broken header, which is displayed on my laptop. I have no idea why the image gets spliced like that, I have tried using `background-repeat : no-repeat`, but it just splits the image in the middle of the page.
Here's my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "fr">
    <head>
        <title>Agence ReArt</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href = "ReArt.css" rel = "stylesheet" media = "all" type = "text/css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <header id = bannière>
                <h1>ReArt</h1>
                <button id = "centerButton" class = "button">Placeholder</button>
                <button id = "rightButton" class = "button">Nous contacter</button>
                <button id = "leftButton" class = "button">Nous découvrir</button>
            </header>
            
        </body>
    
</html>
```

And my CSS :

```
header#bannière {
    display : center;
    height : 225px;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-items : center;
    color : #1BBCED;
    text-shadow : #000 0 0 .2em;
    background-image : url(./Ressources/landscape.jpg);
}
header#bannière > h1 {
    font: bold calc(1em + 2 * (100vw - 120px) / 100) 'Dancing Script', cursive, fantasy;
    text-align : center;
}
.button {
    margin : 0;
    position : absolute;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font : bold calc(1em + 2 * (50vw - 80px) / 100) 'Dancing Script', cursive, fantasy;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
button#centerButton {
    top : 25%;
    left : 50%;
}
button#rightButton {
    top: 25%;
    left: 90%;
}
button#leftButton {
    top: 25%;
    left: 10%;
}
body {
    background-color : white; /* #A55C9F #1BCCED #243797 */
}
```

This is obviously nothing professional, nothing more than a school project, but not knowing how to fix this or even where it comes from is annoying. Thank you to whoever will take the time to answer my question!

Comment: A small tip: Never use special characters in CSS class names. instead of `bannière` use `banniere` for example.

Comment: Could you share differences in browsers? Maybe even OS? (If it is shown in the picture, just know that my school has blocked imgur through a proxy, so I can't view it at the moment)

Comment: Hi @Coffezilla I thought that as well as a-zA-Z0-9 you could use Unicode characters above (and including) 00A0 - is that wrong?

Comment: Yes. Even though browser support many unconventional code ( in css, html, javascript...), some of those things (like the special characters) you should avoid. If is not conventional it means that you can not confirm if its gonna work everywhere like for instance, it works in Chrome today, but you can not be sure if it will work in the next Safari release or even in mobile phones. Of course, if your just playing around, its ok, but for comercial projects it's trivial to keep your code following the guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I didn't specify this in my post, but the display on laptop was working just fine until I tried to insert another image in the header aside from the background one, and it all went downhill from there, even going back to an earlier version of the code wouldn't fix it. I did remove the special characters just in case but I'm glad I wasn't expecting much from that.

Comment: @Coffezilla sorry but I remain confused. Can you point me to the guidelines?

Comment: Can you look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility on your laptop to see exactly what is setting the height and what the computed value actually is? Also display: center isn't something I recognise (though I can't see that as being a problem in this case).

Comment: I just checked, rounded up, the computed values are the same as the ones I put in. What I find weird (or maybe that's normal and I've just never paid attention) is that the width value at 100% on my laptop is almost double the one I get on my PC with a much bigger screen. I assume that means I'll have to double the height value when I want to work on laptop until I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should set width of background image to 100vw. It translates to 100% of Viewport Width, which means the image will now occupy 100% of available screen width independently of its actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `background-size: cover` in combination with `background-repeat: no-repeat` for your header image.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Thank you! but it only fixed half of the issue (literally), the header now spans from left to right in a single image like intended, but the displayed height is still halved on laptop compared to PC, to the point where the buttons don't appear. I tried tempering with `background-size`  to change the height, but the only thing I get is a squashed image.